# Random write with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I wonder if there is an efficient way to 

1. write extra information to an existed json file ?

2. remove a value from the json array?

My Json file:

```
[
    {"name": "A","age": 1,"sex": "male"},
    {"name": "B","age": 2,"sex": "female"},
    {"name": "C","age": 3,"sex": "male"}
]
```

If I want to append another value to the json array,

```
{"name": "D","age": 4,"sex": "female"}
```

How can i continue writing to it, without having rewriting the whole json file again ?

The expected result will be:

```
    [
        {"name": "A","age": 1,"sex": "male"},
        {"name": "B","age": 2,"sex": "female"},
        {"name": "C","age": 3,"sex": "male"},
        {"name": "D","age": 4,"sex": "female"}
    ]
```

or if I want to remove a field in the json array

```
[
    {"name": "A","age": 1,"sex": "male"},
    {"name": "B","age": 2,"sex": "female"}
]
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: This seems more appropriate for a DB than JSON, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes :) but for my purpose, I only need to maintain a small amount of data, thus using DB is not a lightweight for my application

Comment: How about an in-memory DB, such as HSQL?

Comment: but with in-memory DB, can I be able to store my data on disk also ?